# Control Webots from external Python IDE

Tags: python, robotics, webots

Is it possible to control Webots from external Python IDE (like pyCharm) ? I would appreciate if there is an example showing how to do so and location of modules to be added. Thanks

Comment: If I understand well, you would like to use PyCharm to create and debug Webots controllers, right? On which OS (I recently have issues with this on Windows)?

Comment: You are correct @FabienRohrer. I am working on Windows and I hope to see a short example of external python script for moving a model and if possible getting images from the scene. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you thought about implementing a TCP/IP connection between your project and a Webots Supervior controller?

Comment: Is there any API documentation for interacting with Webots Supervisor controller?

Comment: Yes, here: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor

Comment: Thanks, Fabien for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is some new documentation on how to run Webots robot controllers within PyCharm [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-pycharm-with-webots).